# Blackjack simulator (to check)

Tags: python, random, python-2.7, nested-loops

I wrote a Blackjack simulator. The goal was to estimate dealer's likelihood to bust. Notice that dealer must draw when on 16 and must stand on 17. If the dealer's hand contains an ace, it should be counted as 11 when that results in a total between 17 and 21 inclusive; otherwise, the ace should be counted as 1. The program seems to be working but I'm not one hundred certain though. Here is the core of the program. Can you examine whether the code is flawed, please?

```
def simNGames(n):
    holds = busts = 0
    for i in range(n):
        score = simOneGame()
        if score <= 21:
            holds += 1
        else:
            busts += 1
    return holds, busts

def simOneGame():
    score = 0
    cardsVal = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]
    while not gameOver(score):
        dealerScore = choice(cardsVal)

        # in case dealer hits an ace
        if dealerScore == 11:
            if score >= 6 and score <= 10:
                score += 11
            else:
                score += 1
        else:
            score += dealerScore

    return score

def gameOver(score):
    return score >= 17 and score <= 21 or score >=22
```

Comment: If you simulate lots of games in a row, you should take into account the fact that the decks get depleted of the particular cards that the dealer draws (the dealer is less likely to draw the same card again). If you simulate a small number of games then this effect can largely be ignored since Blackjack is usually played with many decks.

Answer (score 0):

Overall the logic seems fine.

My suggestion would be to write some [Unit Tests](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) for specific cases you are worried about.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the effort of reading through this. Thanks for the suggestion, I'm yet to learn about Unit testing.